# get value of a checkbox which is unchecked based on its class name

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of a checkbox which is unchecked based on its class and using this:

```js
var checkboxVal = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='"+ someVal +"']:not(:checked)").val();

if (chekboxVal == 'C')
{
  //do something;
}
```

```html
<input id = "1" type = "checkbox" class="someVal" value = "A" >
<input id = "2" type = "checkbox" class="someVal" value = "B" >
<input id = "3" type = "checkbox" class="someVal" value = "C" >
<input id = "4" type = "checkbox" class="someVal" value = "D" >
```

But I am always getting checkboxVal as 'A' if that is not checked at all. I would like to get 'C' if 'C' is unchecked and not 'A' which is not checked at all. Any help?

Comment: Your checkboxes do not have a `name` attribute on them, so that is likely causing a problem in your selector. Also, since they are checkboxes, more than one of them could be unchecked.

Comment: You'd need to loop through the results as multiple checkboxes could be unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st**: you need to include jquery

**2nd**: you need to set the name attribute to the inputs

**3rd**: you need to loop through them by using `.each()`

```
var checkboxVal = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='"+ someVal +"']:not(:checked)");
checkboxVal.each(function(){
  var Thisval = $(this).val();
  if (Thisval == 'C')
  {
    //do something;
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
  }
});
```

**Demo 1**

```js
var checkboxVal = $("input[type='checkbox'][name=someVal]:not(:checked)");
checkboxVal.each(function(){
  var ThisVal = $(this).val();
  if(ThisVal === 'C'){
    //do something;
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "1" type = "checkbox" name="someVal" class="someVal" value = "A" >
<input id = "2" type = "checkbox" name="someVal" class="someVal" value = "B" >
<input id = "3" type = "checkbox" name="someVal" class="someVal" value = "C" >
<input id = "4" type = "checkbox" name="someVal" class="someVal" value = "D" >
```

**Demo 2**

```js
var checkboxVal = $("input[type='checkbox'][name=someVal]");
checkboxVal.on('change',function(){
  var checked_or_not = this.checked,
      ThisVal = $(this).val();
  if(checked_or_not === true){
    alert('This an input '+ThisVal+' is checked');
  }else{
    alert('This an input '+ThisVal+' is Unchecked now');
  }
  checkboxVal.each(function(){
    var checked_or_not = this.checked;
    var ThisVal = $(this).val();
    if(checked_or_not === false){
      //do something;
      alert('Input with Id : '+$(this).attr('id')+' is unchecked');
    } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "1" type = "checkbox" name="someVal" class="someVal" value = "A" >
<input id = "2" type = "checkbox" name="someVal" class="someVal" value = "B" >
<input id = "3" type = "checkbox" name="someVal" class="someVal" value = "C" >
<input id = "4" type = "checkbox" name="someVal" class="someVal" value = "D" >
```

Comment: I believe name = "someVal" is what you ment?

Comment: I am still getting 'A' which is not checked at all. Sorry.

Comment: @User2309 while you didn't set it on your code and define it as a variable .. it may be anything .. so I assumed any `name` attribute .. you can change it as you like its just a demo .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: @User2309 anyway I updated my answer with `name="someVal"`

Comment: Thanks, but 'ThisVal' is still showing up as 'A' which is never checked or unchecked.

Comment: @User2309 I updated my answer with `change event` this is all I have for `radio` inputs just play around it

Answer (score 0):

You selector has [name='someVal'], while input has class="someVal".

It should be eiter

```
var checkboxVal = $("input."+ someVal +"[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").val();
```

or

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" name="someVal" value="A">
<input id="2" type="checkbox" name="someVal" value="B">
<input id="3" type="checkbox" name="someVal" value="C">
<input id="4" type="checkbox" name="someVal" value="D">
```